# Use my own wordlist for single mode in John the Ripper

Tags: password-cracking

I would like to apply the complete set of mangling rules to a reduced wordlist of user information. How can I do that? I know that's what JtR is supposed to do by default in the single crack mode but if I take the hashes in one computer and try to crack them in another the information that JtR may use in the second computer isn't useful to crack the passwords.

I would also like to know where is the wordlist that JtR uses for the single crack mode.

Answer (score 1):

First, (unless you're talking about "single crack" mode generally), I'm not sure what you mean by "a reduced wordlist of user information". It sounds like you may be describing a simple wordlist attack, which is executed with the `--wordlist [wordlist]` option.

Second, from [the JtR modes documentation](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/MODES.shtml), the wordlist used by "single crack" mode is:

> It will use the login names, "GECOS" / "Full Name" fields, and users'
>   home directory names as candidate passwords, also with a large set of
>   mangling rules applied.

The way to run a "single crack" attack on a separate system is to simply supply the **entire `/etc/shadow` entry** to JtR as the target "hash". (In other words, it's not pulling the data from `/etc/shadow` directly; instead, you are extracting that information and supplying it separately.) When run in "single crack" mode, it knows how to parse each field and use them accordingly.